# Generate all combinations from a limited list of single digit numbers equating to a digital root

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to generate a "Nonary Game" based on the data you feed to the code.

In the game Zero Escape 999, there are 9 players, each carrying an index from 1 to 9. The players are forced to split up into groups due to Numbered Doors blocking their path, which requires from 3 to 5 players to sum their indexes and create a digital root. Example:

Two doors numbered 4 and 5.

Available players: 123456789.

One of many viable split-ups:

Group #4: 1237=1+2+3+7=13=1+3=4, players #1, #2, #3, #7 can make it through the door

Group #5: 45689=4+5+6+8+9=32=3+2=5, players #4, #5, #6, #8, #9 can make it through the door.

Now this is where my code plays in:
The objective is to generate a long list of possible combinations from currently available player list and display all the outcomes where:

A) There are players left behind, and

B) No players are left behind.

The current code snippet works as intended, however, it cannot account for more than 2 doors and does not let you display all the available combinations should you provide only a single door number. I am stuck on this part as I cannot come up with a good, recursive method that would account for 3-door split-up possibilities in a decent manner.

The minimum amount of groups should be 2, and the maximum amount of groups should be equal to the number of doors available.

So if there are three doors, the script will spit out from two to three teams. If there are four doors, it'll display from two to four teams, etc.

To minimize the amount of data displayed, I am using a smaller pool of players of 123456; 2 players per door minimum, 4 maximum and two numbered doors 4 and 8. This is the console output:

`Please input the total players in a single string, e.g. 123456789. 123456
Please input lowest amount of players per door. 2
Please input highest amount of players per door. 4
Please input amount of doors. 2
Please input number for door 1. 4
Please input number for door 2. 8
The digital root of the doors is 3.
4: 13, 8: 26    left behind: 45
4: 13, 8: 2456  left behind:
4: 256, 8: 134  left behind:
4: 346, 8: 125  left behind:
4: 1246, 8: 35  left behind:
4: 1345, 8: 26  left behind:
Displaying all possible combos.`

```py
from itertools import combinations

def digit_root(n): 
    return (n - 1) % 9 + 1 if n else 0


players = input('Please input the total players in a single string, e.g. 123456789. ')
player_combinations = [''.join(l) for i in range(len(players)) for l in combinations(players, i+1)]
minplayers = int(input("Please input lowest amount of players per door. "))
maxplayers = int(input("Please input highest amount of players per door. "))
while True:
    doortotal = int(input("Please input amount of doors. "))

    doors = []
    for i in range(doortotal):
        doors.append({"num": int(input("Please input number for door {}. ".format(i+1))), "combos": []})

        for combo in player_combinations:
            if len(combo) >= minplayers and len(combo) <= maxplayers and digit_root(int(combo)) == doors[i]["num"]:
                doors[i]["combos"].append(combo)

    door_root = digit_root(sum([door["num"] for door in doors]))
    print("The digital root of the doors is {}.".format(door_root))

    # for door in doors:
    #   print('Door #{} individual combos:'.format(door["num"]))
    #   print('\n'.join(door["combos"]))

    def get_combo(comboA, comboB):
        if any(a for a in comboA if a in comboB) == True: #We can't have the same player entering one or several doors at once
            return None
        combo = comboA + comboB
        dif = ''.join([a for a in players if not (a in combo)])
        print("{}: {}, {}: {} \tleft behind: {}".format(doors[0]["num"], comboA, doors[1]["num"], comboB, dif))
        return combo

    for comboA in doors[0]["combos"]:
        for comboB in doors[1]["combos"]:
            get_combo(comboA, comboB)

    input("Displaying all possible combos.")
```

The script is expected to account for more than 2 doors and list all available combinations for teams of 2 to door count. I need assistance in creating a viable recursive loop that goes in such fashion:

`3 doors - 3,7,8.`

Display possible combinations for:

`Doors 3+7, doors 3+8, doors 7+8, doors 3+7+8`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a lot of info. You might want to make a [mre] to make it easier for people to both understand the problem and to write an answer.

Comment: @wjandrea Yeah, I'll try to cut down on info but I've got myself so stumped I don't even know what I can remove from the equation in here.

Comment: Last line: `Door 3, door 7, door 8`. You said that minimum doors number should be 2. Why listing the single doors?

Comment: @CristiFati That's a good point, resolved that. I think I'll make my code only display single doors if the user specifically says "1 door".